# I am unable to do insert into a table along with Merge command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-express

Unable to perform Merge with Insert statement (for an accounting process)

Table1 contains GRList for write off (based on date on Table3)

Table2 Contains All GR details (all information from 1-jan-2010 to till date)

Table3 contains Oldest Claim date (eg: 1-Apr-2018)

so from the above scenario Oldest Claim date (eg: 1-Apr-2018) gets picked up from Table 3 and then it searches in Table 2 for the GRs which is before the extracted date ( <= 1-apr-2018) and populates the record (from 1-jan-2010 to 31-mar-2018) in Table 1

**Code Tried in SQL**

```
MERGE Table1 As Target
Using (select column1, column2 From Table2 AS tbl2 INNER JOIN Table3 as tbl3
ON tbl2.column1 = tbl3.column1
WHERE
tbl2.column1 = tbl3.column1 AND tbl2.column2 = tbl3.column2) AS SOURCE

ON
(Target.Column1 = Source.Column1 AND Target.Column2 = Source.Column2  AND Target.Column5 <= Source.Column5 )

WHEN MATCHED AND 
Target.Column1 = Source.Column1 AND Target.Column2 = Source.Column2

THEN UPDATE SET Target.Column4='Updated'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT 
(Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES
(Source.Column1, Source.Column2, Source.Column3)
```

**ERROR**

Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
The conversion of the nvarchar value '3000143371 ' overflowed an int column.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

One of your Target table column data type is INT. You are trying to insert a value that is to big for data type INT
Try changing your target column data type from INT to BIGINT.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but I tried updating only one column which is of nvarchar datatype in both the target and source tables and still getting the same error.